# Computing geodesic distance - geometry and STDistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, arcgis

I've problem with computing geodesic distance in MS SQL Server 2014.
Here is my SQL code:

```
select
    test.point.STDistance(test.point1)
from
(
    select
        geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(5741830.339752582 6594489.991426462)', 2177) as point,
        geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(5737417.638193398 6606094.640481565)', 2177) as point1
) test
```

The result of the query(computing distance between points) is 12415,3056644823 meters.

When I run ARC GIS service to compute this distance I received two values:

- 12415.305664482255 for non-geodesic distance
- 12328.8174576046   for geodesic distance

MSSQL query returns non-geodesic distance. I don't know what is the diffrence between non-geodesic and geodesic distance, but I would like to get geodesic value in my SQL query.  Is there any possibility to compute geodesic distance using this method?

Comment: From [**manual**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type) `STDistance() returns the shortest LineString between two geography types. This is a close approximate to the geodesic distance. The deviation of STDistance() on common earth models from the exact geodesic distance is no more than .25%.`

Comment: i think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stdistance-geometry-data-type) function documentation is correct. But there isn't any word about geodesic distance.

Comment: Your manual is from 2008 mine is from 2012

Comment: your link refers to type _geography_ not _geometric_